# B&R Automation Studio, not able to set breakpoints after upgrade

Tags: plc, br-automation-studio

Automation Studio was upgraded from 4.3.6.57 to 4.5.2.102.  Everything works well except Automation Studio does not present any icons in the left gutter to set breakpoints.

How to get the breakpoints back?

Comment: Someone with a rep of 1500 please create the categories of 'automation-studio' and 'br-automation' and add to this question.  Thanks

Comment: New tag `br-automation-studio` created.

Comment: @eglease  Thank you  very much.

Answer (score 1):

The setting for the GCC Compiler needs to be set to V6.3.0.  This is in the menu : Project -> Change Runtime Versions -> Build -> GCC Version.